# Is there a way to determine what process is rebooting a server?

Tags: linux, qemu, kvm, reboot, libvirt

I have a kvm vm that seems to be rebooting randomly. I'm not seeing anything in syslog about reboot, shutdown, error, core dump, panic, etc. No errors in libvirtd log on the host either, no errors in the qemu logs, and no errors on the host whatsoever.

It just seems like some random process might be invoking the reboot syscall inside the vm? That's all I can think of...

How do I determine what is causing this? OS is Debian.

Comment: Start qemu with the -no-reboot and -no-shutdown option so it will halt the emulation instead of rebooting then maybe you can see what's wrong.

Comment: I do rely on the services running on this system, and I would prefer to take a more Linux system approach to solving this, vs the virtualization side, if possible. If it's a random process invoking the reboot syscall, then the virtualization stuff wouldn't be relevant.

Comment: But it may be a kernel panic which you can see on the console then.

Comment: I tested and kernel panics get logged to syslog and /var/crash. There is no kernel panic in my case.

Comment: How random are the reboots?  Running `last | grep reboot` on the VM should show recent reboot times.  Are you certain something on the host is not interfering?  Have you checked if the out of memory killer was invoked on your VM process or if there is some virtualization task rebooting the VM?

Comment: There is no oom killer invoked, there is nothing in any relevant logs, and qemu / libvirt / kvm seems fine, nothing in those logs either. Is there really no way to log if for example a process invokes the reboot syscall? I don't mind having to write a daemon in c that checks for this but I wouldn't really know where to start.

Comment: What does that mean: "there is nothing in any relevant logs"? Can't you see anything about the shutdown and the system suddenly is booting?

Comment: If [`reboot()` syscall](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/764949/209677) is never called, might be something on the host. Are you overclocking? Enough RAM? Can you test on bare metal? Check host syslog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind putting hands to C code, then you can write a simple kernel module that intercepts the reboot/shutdown call and saves information via `printk()`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71729062/how-to-correctly-intercept-system-calls-in-the-linux-kernel-5) might be a good start. To get to know who's calling your modified handler, check out [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60041658/how-to-get-the-process-id-of-the-program-that-called-a-system-function).

### Test code

I have tried to develop the hints above, and came up with the following code.

On my own home system (Ubuntu 22.04-LTS) it does compile and the kernel module gets installed, and seems to work with *some* symbols: e.g. `__do_sys_swapon`:

```
Dec 15 22:38:51 mintaka kernel: [82534.879652] __do_sys_swapon called by PID 5381 (swapon)
```

But there seem to be several reboot-like calls in `/proc/kallsyms`, so I'm afraid you'll need either several kprobes, or quite a bit of trial and error. `__do_sys_reboot` does not seem to get logged if I invoke `reboot` from the prompt.

```c
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/printk.h>
#include <linux/kprobes.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

/**
 * Pre handler
 * @return int  unless you're a kprobe geek
 */
static noinline int handler(struct kprobe *p, struct pt_regs *regs) {
    struct task_struct *task = current;
    printk(KERN_EMERG "%s called by PID %d (%s)\n", p->symbol_name, (int)task->pid, task->comm);
    return 0;
}

// Verify that the symbol name is present in /proc/kallsyms
static struct kprobe kp = {
    .symbol_name    = "__do_sys_reboot",
    .pre_handler    = handler
};
/**
 * Module initialization
 *
 * @returns int
 */

int init_module(void) {
    int ret;
    printk(KERN_INFO "loading whistlebooter\n");
    // register_kprobe ultimately returns e.g. arch_copy_kprobe() which succeeds with 0
    ret = register_kprobe(&kp);
    if (ret < 0) {
        if (-2 == ret) {
            printk(KERN_INFO "register_kprobe did not find the requested symbol\n");
        } else {
            printk(KERN_INFO "register_kprobe failed with code %d\n", ret);
        }
    } else {
        printk(KERN_INFO "kprobe registered at addr=%p for '%s'\n", kp.addr, kp.symbol_name);
    }
    return 0;
}

/**
 * @returns void
 */
void cleanup_module(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "unloading whistlebooter\n");
    unregister_kprobe(&kp);
}
```

#### Makefile

```
# vim: tabstop=4 sw=4 noexpandtab
obj-m += mymodule.o
PWD := $(CURDIR)

all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

To compile, just run '`make`'.

Comment: Thank you! I made some good progress just from the original two links you provided, but I ran into the same issue, looks like any syscall like open gets logged with no issue, but reboot doesn't get logged for whatever reason. I went with the modifying sys_call_table approach. I'm not sure what the problem is with the reboot syscall, compared to other syscalls.