# Reboot command doesn't invoke reboot system call?

Tags: systemd, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, c, reboot

OS is Debian.

As per my question here:

[Is there a way to determine what process is rebooting a server?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/763084/is-there-a-way-to-determine-what-process-is-rebooting-a-server)

I wrote a kernel module to intercept the reboot syscall via modifying the syscall table.

Basically just saving the old function pointer via:

```
old_reboot = (void *) *(sys_call_table + __NR_reboot);
```

Then making `sys_call_table` writable and doing:

```
*(sys_call_table + __NR_reboot) = (unsigned long) my_reboot;
```

Then switching `sys_call_table` back to read only. My reboot syscall looks like this:

```
asmlinkage long my_reboot(int magic1, int magic2, unsigned int cmd, void __user *arg)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Intercepted sys_reboot\n");
    return old_reboot(magic1, magic2, cmd, arg);
}
```

Then I test my code by executing the command "reboot" in bash.

However, I don't see my custom reboot function logging to dmesg / syslog, but I do see logging when my module is loaded or unloaded, so at least that part is working.

So then I tried the exact same thing, just with the `open` syscall instead of the `reboot` syscall, and it works perfectly. So I am able to intercept the open syscall, get the pid of the process that invoked it, log the info to dmesg / syslog, etc.

Why would I be able to intercept the open syscall via this method but not the reboot syscall?

Does rebooting actually invoke the reboot system call? Or am I doing something else wrong here?

Edit:

Wrote a small program to invoke the reboot syscall directly and it works. (I am able to intercept the reboot syscall via kernel module)

reboot_test.c:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/reboot.h>

int main()
{
        sync();
        reboot(RB_AUTOBOOT);
        return 0;
}
```

However, when I try rebooting using the reboot command, I don't see my intercepted reboot syscall logged.

As an additional test, doing:

```
strace -f reboot
```

doesn't show the reboot syscall, but using my small c program, strace does show the reboot syscall. (As the last line before rebooting)

1. Why doesn't systemd use the reboot syscall?
2. How do I configure my system so that all reboots use the reboot syscall?

Comment: Could you please post the output of *type -a reboot* ? (in order to ensure that the reboot command you used is not in fact linking to systemctl, in which case and if you still get the original /sbin/reboot, force its use when willing to reboot.

Comment: I get: reboot is /usr/sbin/reboot and reboot is /sbin/reboot. Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: so what happens if you fire **/sbin/reboot** as root. Do you get the output of your printk ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, I looked. And, on my system, reboot is a simlink to systemctl. But apparently, kernel panic can trigger an immediate reboot, bypassing `systemctl`

Comment: Please provide more info regarding your motherboard and arch if x86(_64) there are several possible reboot types. (bios, acpi, kbd, triple, efi, or pci) that can forced on the boot command line, that can as well get forced running through some quirck (in arch/x86/kernel/reboot.c) depending on your motherboard. Please do check.

Comment: system is a kvm vm

Comment: Systemd is in the middle, but [pass to the syscall](https://shorturl.at/hqF35). Maybe you have to check [the source code](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/main/src/systemctl/systemctl.c) I wonder if the syscall is trigged if you try [`systemctl --force --force reboot`](https://shorturl.at/pGHQ5) (should invoke the `reboot` syscall directly) or [`echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.4/admin-guide/sysrq.html#how-do-i-use-the-magic-sysrq-key).

Comment: What happens if, as part of your reboot_test.c, you change RB_AUTOBOOT for RB_HALT_SYSTEM ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is not a complete answer.  In examining the systemd source code, it appears that when an urgent reboot is needed (perhaps due to the 'reboot -f' command ??), that a direct system call is made to the same entry point as reboot(2), however bypassing glibc, in order to add a 5th argument, unsupported by the glibc library.    When a conventional reboot is called this appears to invoke /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-shutdown which will at least sync, umount filesystems before reboot.  It *appears* to make the reboot syscall, but the logic is quite complex.